# Row reducing: Finding linear condition of column space of a matrix

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, gaussian-elimination

**Question**

> For the matrix
> $$
> A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & x & x^2 \\
> 1 & y & y^2 \\
> 1 & z & z^2 \\
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
> the set
> $$S=\{\textbf b \in \mathbb{R^3} : \textbf{b} = A\textbf{x} \text{ for some }\textbf x \in \mathbb{R^3}\}$$
> is the column space for $A$.
> Find the condition for augmented matrix $A\textbf{v}$
> so that the vector $
> \textbf{v}=\begin{pmatrix}
> x  \\ y  \\ z \\\end{pmatrix}
> $ belongs to the set $S$.

**My Attempt**
We find that saying $\textbf v \in S$ is equivalent to $x,y$ and $z$ satisfying a linear condition of the form $ax+by+cz=0$. Specifically, this condition is equivalent to?

I'm trying to find the linear condition by row reducing and Gaussian Elimination method, however this is the first time I've seen an augmented matrix where the $x, y$ and $z$ is on the right hand side of the vertical line like in the question.

1. Does this mean I can make these assumptions?
   $a-2b+2c = x\\
          a-4b+2c = y\\
          -6a+18b-12c = z$
2. Do I then find the value of $a, b,$ and $c$ in terms of $x, y$ and $z$ and substitute it to $ax+by+cz=0$ ?

Comment: You have to find a condition relating $x,y,z$ such that the system is consistent. So row reduce it and see what is the condition to be imposed for existence of a solution. For example, if the system was $\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}1&1&x\\1&1&y\end{array}\right]$, then row reduction will give $\begin{bmatrix}1&1&| &x\\0&0&|&x-y\end{bmatrix}$. So for consistency you will need $x-y=0$.

Comment: @AnuragA got it, thanks!